# How do I extract a .tar.xz file?

Tags: tar, compression, archive

Some software seems to be distributed in a new archive format:

```
$ file node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: XZ compressed data
```

How do I extract this, preferably using tar (like I can with gzip or bzip2) ?

Comment: “New” is relative ;-). GNU `tar` has supported `xz` archives since March 2009.

Comment: @StephenKitt Kind of. It's a different question, so not a duplicate I think, but the solution is the same. Like 'what fruit is in a walford salad?' and 'what keeps the doctor away?' are separate question with the same answer 'apple'. Not sure what the policy is here.

Comment: @mikemaccana "duplicate" questions are simply sign-posts that are worded differently but have the same solution -- exactly like this. People searching for various wording will hit the various entry-point "duplicate" questions and find themselves redirected to the single solution. It helps keep answers high-quality on SE.

Comment: @JeffSchaller they're worded differently because they're different questions (see waldorf salad vs doctors example given previously), but I do understand. I'm glad this still exists as it'll help others who needs to extract an .xz even if they get the answer from a different question.

Comment: @Bib Please be kind in comments. I had no idea that `tar` even supported non-gzip non-bzip2 formats - last I checked (which was a decade ago) it didn't, so I imagined using an external command and piping to tar.

Comment: @Bib consider that the manual for tar on my Arch is more than 1k lines, man pages are really not easy to understand for those not used to them, and many users won't even know how to search through a man page as `/` isn't something you'd guess if you didn't know it. So please be a bit more patient, we're here to answer questions, after all, so we can't expect people to already know.

Comment: IMO the duplicate closure here is wrong. The solution in Mike's self-answer here is better than the answers at any of the dupes, since it's tailored to `.tar.xz` files (rather than compressed files in general) and doesn't require installing additional software on distros that already ship with `tar`.

Comment: I would agree with @MarkAmery. If people want to close it again, so be it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several `tar` implementations (at least GNU `tar`¹, `star` and libarchive's `bsdtar`) already handle this compression format, you can either:

- Don't explicitly specify a format and let tar detect the compression automatically (with either gtar², bsdtar or star³):

  ```
  tar -xf node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```

  Or if you like to watch the progress:

  ```
  tar -xvf node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```
- Use `-J`/`--xz` with GNU's or libarchive's or `-xz` with `star` to tell `tar` to expect XZ

  ```
  tar -xJf node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```

  ```
  gtar -xJf node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```

  ```
  bsdtar -xJf node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```

  ```
  star -x -xz -f node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
  ```

Without those specific `tar` implementations or with the standard `pax` command (`tar` has been removed from the UNIX standard as there were too many incompatibilities between implementations), decompress the archive with `xz`⁴ and then unpack the archive via a pipe:

```
xz -dc node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar -xvf -
```

```
xz -dc node-v18.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz | pax -rv
```

---

<sup>¹ generally called `tar` on GNU systems, but often `gtar` or `gnutar` or `gnu-tar` on other systems if installed there beside the system's one.</sup>

<sup>² with GNU tar, that doesn't work if the file is passed on stdin with `-` as the file name or if the file is no seekable in which case you need to pass the `-J` option.</sup>

<sup>³ with star, that doesn't work if the file is not seekable in which case you do need to use the `-xz` option. `tar -xf -` still works as long as stdin is seekable.</sup>

<sup>⁴ beware failures of `xz` may not always be detected in that case. Most Bourne-like shells now support the `pipefail` option from ksh93 which can help here; set with `set -o pipefail`.</sup>